# Creating a reference to an object without using ":" in Lua

Tags: oop, object, lua, self

My goal is to write an addon for a GUI written in Lua. It should replace the creation of a window without the need of changeing the code of the GUI itself. The original function creating the window looks like this:

```
function GUIclass.createWindow(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)
    -- do stuff
    return window
end
```

My method looks like this:

```
function MyClass.createWindow(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)
    local foo = self.attributeOne -- doesn't work, as self is undefined
    -- do some more stuff wich requires foo
    return window
end

... and later on
MyClassInst = MyClass:new()
```

Note that both functions are in different files. The idea I had was replacing the pointer to the old function after it has been initialised

```
GUIclass.createWindow = MyClass.createWindow
```

Everything works fine, except I seem to be unable to get a reference to the instance of MyClass in MyClass.createWindow. I tried using

```
local self = MyClassInst
```

in the MyClass.createWindow but it is nil. I also dislike this because it is limited to one instance of the Class. As stated in the title, ":" also woun't work as the function gets called via "GUIclass.createWindow(args)" (which now points to MyClass.createWindow).

So how can I get a reference to the instance of a class without using ":"?

Comment: Long shot, haven't done lua forever: `function MyClass.createWindow(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)`
I seem to remember something about putting self as the first argument?

Comment: Does the original GUIclass.createWindow refer to self in its code? If so, is there a 'local self' declared in the file it lives in?

Comment: Are the createWindow functions both supposed to be constructors? IOW, are they supposed to return a new instance of GUIclass and/or MyClass? (I assume MyClass is a subclass of GUIclass.)

Comment: @FrederikSpang yeah, that is what : is doing, but as I don't have control over the call of the function, defining it with ":" will only mess up my arguments as I only get 5 passed but require 6.

Comment: @Odoth no the original GUIclass.createWindow doesn't need a reference to itself (guess you could call it a static method in other languages).

Comment: @luther both classes are independent. the only thing they have in common is the propose to create an instance of "window" which later on gets shown on the screen. My goal is to pass the "window" created by MyClass back and making it replace the "window" of the GUI classes method.

Comment: Which Lua version are you using and is the original `createWindow` a Lua or C function? Also, do you have at least read access to the original `createWindow` function? It would help a bit to see it's implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating a new window object, there's no need for a self parameter. Instead, create the new instance within the MyClass.createWindow function. Do this either by using a table constructor ({}) or by calling another constructor function. Example:

```
local oldCreateWindow = GUIclass.createWindow
function MyClass.createWindow(...)
  local window = oldCreateWindow(...)
  local foo = window.attributeOne
  -- do some more stuff wich requires foo
  return window
end
```

---

I think I understand your problem better now. I believe you'll be better off with a closure than with a class.

```
-- MyClass is actually just a table with lots of attributes that change a lot.
local MyClass = {}
local function createWindow(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)
  local foo = MyClass.attributeOne
  -- do some more stuff wich requires foo
  return window
end

GUIclass.createWindow = createWindow
```

After that, any changes you make to MyClass should be visible to GUIclass.createWindow.

Comment: How do you figure out what `self` should be pointing to? As you define the function with "." no parameter named `self` will be passed to your function.

Comment: Whoa, I screwed it up. 'self' should be 'window'. Sorry about that. Edited to correct.

Comment: The problem here is that `window` doesn't have an attribute named `attributeOne`. It is the instance of `MyClass` that does have the attribute. I am not passing back an instance of `MyClass` as `window`. Rather I am trying to create a `window` in `MyClassInst` using attributes of `MyClassInst` to do so while monkey-patching the function `GUIclass.createWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just post as an answer..

Try:

```
function MyClass.createWindow(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)
```

As far as I remember from lua, that equals:

```
function MyClass:createWindow(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)
```

Just like

```
class:something()
```

equals

```
class.something(class)
```

Comment: While true this doesn't answer the question because, as he said, the original function is called with dot syntax and so does not get a self argument. (Even if it was called with colon syntax it would get the `GUIclass` as self and not his class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (mostly) that's sort of the point of what <kbd>:</kbd> does for you here.

If you are calling the function with a <kbd>.</kbd> you don't have any context for the call other than the arguments you give it (and any closed-over variables that function has).

If you wanted to create multiple instances of your custom `createWindow` function you could have them close over some class instance variable and use that internally but you would have to do that manually and have the classes available before-hand. I don't know if that is doable in your situation or not.

I also don't really understand the issues with the code as written.

Are you expecting to have more than one custom `createWindow` function that monkey-patch in to `GUIclass` repeatedly as appropriate? Or why would you need `createWindow` to take a `self` argument the way you've written it?

Comment: The `MyClass.createWindow` should customize the window. To do this, it needs to check on some variables stored as attributes in `MyClassInst`. However I made a mistake posting the question. `MyClass` is the metatable of `MyClassInst`, defining `__index=MyClass`. What I am doing is replacing `GUIclass.createWindow` with `MyClassInst.createWindow` (which is `MyClass.createWindow` as the function is undefined in `MyClassInst`). Therefore I thought it would be possible to create a reference to `MyClassInst`, as the program gets 'redirected' into the instance of the object.

Comment: It isn't being "redirected" anywhere. The "address" of the function is being changed but the function itself (when called) doesn't know anything about how you got to it. To get that you need the colon syntax or a closure.

Comment: I'd guess that was the point where my thoughts went wrong. So there is no chance for me to reference the instance? Or the class?

Comment: Not without getting an argument passed or using a closure. Again though I'm not sure I see the issue here since you can only ever have one function callable as `GUIclass.createWindow` at any given time so I'm not sure how that could need a specific object instance's data to control its operation (such that you couldn't either hard-code or global-ize that without any genericism loss).

Comment: In a constructor, you *could* use a self parameter to refer to the class. (Just remember to use the ':' when both declaring and calling the constructor.) But it wouldn't make sense to create a reference to MyClassInst or to check its attributes, because it hasn't been created yet. (See my answer about creating the instance.)

Comment: @luther That misses the point entirely. See the conversation about *not* being able to use colon syntax here. But yes, I still don't understand the desired usage scenario where this functionality needs to work this way.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah, I forgot about him not being able to control the function call, sorry.

Comment: I guess I've lead myself to astray here. As attributes only have values when instanced as an object, I was trying to refer to the object, so that I get access to those attributes. You are perfectly right, when saying that only one thing modifying the function makes sense. Still I struggle to reference even a single table within my function, as something like `local myTable = MyClassInst` leads to `myTable` being nil and I have no idea why.

Comment: Depending on a given instance existing in a function of the class itself is an odd dependency to have. Especially if you expect to have multiple instances of the class around at once. What are you trying to have your custom function do exactly such that it needs external data like this?

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger: That's because MyClassInst starts out as nil. Try doing 'local myTable = {}'. Then return myTable at the end.

Comment: Yes, Ethan this dependancy is odd, that's why I was asking for different way to do so. I rethough what I want to do and don't have any more need for multiple instances of my class. The window itself contains a list of features which are unordered by default. What I want my function to do is to sort those features with respect to an order defined in an attribute of `MyClassInst`. As the desired order may vary I want to be able to change the sorting criteria at runtime. Thats why I need to check an attribute each time the function is called.